E-commerce MVC problems
Im working on a e-commerce for a school project, using MVC for the first time, everything seems to works fine exept for displaying products from the db and displaying users also from the db, since the problem may be the same i will just upload the code for the users because its way short.
First of all i will upload index.php, where i create the session and the connection, and also send the uri to the router (sorry for italians comment everything else is written in english)
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/routers/switchrouter.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/config/dbconfig.php'; 

// inizia la sessione se non esiste già
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
    }

// Crea un'istanza di mysqli utilizzando le variabili dal file dbconfig.php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connessione al database fallita: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$uri = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

$router = new SwitchRouter($conn); // Passa direttamente un'istanza di mysqli al costruttore di SwitchRouter
$router->route($uri);
?>


i dont think router is important for my problem, so i will not upload the code unless someone say it is important.
Now we have userrepository.php, where i do all the query (they works cuz i tried them directly in the db):
<?php

namespace Repositories;

require_once __DIR__ . '/repository.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../models/user.php';

use mysqli;

class UserRepository extends Repository
{
    function __construct(mysqli $conn)
    {
        parent::__construct($conn);
    }

    // Ottiene tutti gli utenti
    public function getAll()
    {
        $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM USERS";

        $result = $this->connection->query($sqlquery);
        if ($result === false) {
            die("Query failed: " . $this->connection->error);
        }
        return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }


then we have userservice.php:
<?php

namespace Services;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../repositories/userrepository.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../models/user.php';
use Repositories\UserRepository;
use mysqli;

class UserService {
    private $userRepository;

    function __construct(mysqli $conn) {
        $this->userRepository = new UserRepository($conn);
    }

    // Restituisce tutti gli user
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->userRepository->getAll();
    }

?>


from the controller i will just upload the part where the problem may be, everything else like login, signup etc works fine
function usersView()
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['role'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['role'] == Role::Admin) {
                $users = $this->userService->getAll();
                require '../../app/views/admin/users.php';
            }
        } else {
            $this->loginView();
        }
    }

for last we have the view, where the users should be displayed
<?php
 require __DIR__ . '/../header.php';
?>

</header>
    <!-- fine header section -->

    <!-- inizio main section -->
    <main class="container">
        <section id="orders" class="mt-5">
            <h2>Users</h2>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">ID</th>
                        <th scope="col">Immagine</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Ruolo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Azioni</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $user->getId() ?></td>
                            <td><img src="<?= $user->getImage() ?>" alt="user image" width="50" height="50"></td>
                            <td><?= $user->getFullName() ?></td>
                            <td><?= $user->getEmail() ?></td>
                            <td><?= $user->getRoleName() ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/users/editView?editUser=<?= $user->getId() ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                <a href="/users/delete?deleteUser=<?= $user->getId() ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
    <!-- fine main section -->

<?php
   require __DIR__ . '/../footer.php';
?>

i tried by debugging $users in the view with count($users) but it was null

You said you have a problem with it, but you haven't told us exactly what the problem is. Do you get any errors, does it show nothing at all, does it redirect you somewhere else?

i should display every user with a button to edit it, but i got nothing, i cant display anything, no errors too

Is it a complete white screen, or do you get the template/table with no rows? Have you checked the server error log?

not completely white, just the part where i should display the users is empty, i got header and css, just cant display the users, there are no server error log, if you need it i can also give the url to the website, like i want the user to be displayed in card, and there are no cards

Sounds like you need to debug the function that retrieves the users, and then follow the flow of logic to determine at what point in your code the problem occurs.  So, for example, does $users contain the data you expect?  Please edit your question and provide debugging details like this.

well, im not that good on it, so as i said i tried to debug but didnt got anything, where and how should i see what is inside $users

I mean this in the most polite way...just stating facts:  we aren't here to teach you how to debug.  It's expected you have learned how to debug your code.  If you don't know how to do that, please take the time to go learn how to do it. It is an essential programming skill.  There are many tutorials and courses online that can help you learn how to debug your code.  Here is a starting point.

I would create a logging function to help debug, or you can just use var_dump() while testing. Start with usersView(), see which line it's hitting -- Is it getting to where it's calling getAll()? Does $users contain data? (Hint, use count($users) and echo/log that data). From there, if it does contain data, double-check with your view. If not, then debug your getAll() function.

you re right about the debugging, i was thinking i may have made an obvius mistake, but i guess it is not that obvius, so im not expecting an answer on how to fix or how to debug, i will try to debug on my own and if i have any news i will just edit the question

i tried to debug and i found out that $users is null, im updating the question too

Silly question, but how many rows do you have in the Users table?

When you update the question, please create a Minimal, Reproduceable Example and remove all of the code that isn't directly related to $users being null.

if you mean on my db i have 5 users

Also, look into how to enable error reporting in PHP, so you can see if the database is returning an error.

i updated the question and removed a lot of useless code, since the problem is on getAll() function or how i send $users to the view

tbh i have to go now, so i cant really do it rn but i will do it probably tomorrow, thanks everybody for the help, btw i dont think db is giving any error because if i try to do the query inside the db its all right, it may be the connection to the db, but it works for login and signup so i dont think it could be the problem either
